# Nginx reverse proxy for multiple domains and subdomains

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, subdomain, multiple-instances

I have server running different sites and i need to config nginx reverse proxy for these domains, (example1.com, example2.com, test.example1.com), where dp I need to configure the domains in nginx for reverse proxy.

Answer (score 4):

multiple `server{}` blocks and `proxy_pass http://origin.server` in `location` blocks.

For example:

```
server {
  test.example1.com;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://origin.text.example1.com;
  }
}
server {
  server_name example1.com;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://origin.example1.com;
  }
}
server {
  server_name example2.com;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://origin.example2.com;
  }
}
```

[nginx Beginner's Guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) and 
[Server names in nginx document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) will help you.

More complex configurations(including /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf, /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf) are available, but that relies on your distribution packages.

Comment: This is also useful if you are running several webservers in docker containers; to direct the different domains to different containers and different IP/port from the main address/80